# How to join two queries keeping “City” as filter for first column

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to join these two separate queries. Each of them on its own works. One is for 2019 and one is for 2018.. I am trying to have 7 total columns. The first being "city" which is where the two queries both share and then 6 more columns (3 for 2019 & 3 for 2018). Thank you for your help!

I've tried using join, but I believe my syntax is off

```
select
"City",
"2019 AAA",
"2019 BBB",
"2019 CCC",
"2018 AAA",
"2018 BBB",
"2018 CCC"

from (
coalesce(city, 'Total') as "City", 
    sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as "2019 AAA",
    sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee)/sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as "2019 BBB",
    sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee) as "2019 CCC"
    from reservations
        join listings on reservations.listings_id = listings.id
        where status = 'confirmed' 
        and ((reservations.check_in_datetime at time zone 'EDT')::timestamp::date > '2019-04-30') 
        and (reservations.check_in_datetime at time zone 'EDT')::timestamp::date < '06-01-2019' 
        and (reservation_confirmed_at at time zone 'EDT')::timestamp::date < '05-27-2019'
        and city <> 'XXXX'
        and reservations.deleted_at is null
            group by rollup(city)
    ) as t2019
Join (
select  coalesce(city, 'Total') as "City", 
    sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as "2018 AAA",
    sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee)/sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as "2018 BBB",
    sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee) as "2018 CCC"
    from reservations
        join listings on reservations.listings_id = listings.id
        where status = 'confirmed' 
        and ((reservations.check_in_datetime at time zone 'EDT')::timestamp::date > '2018-04-30') 
        and (reservations.check_in_datetime at time zone 'EDT')::timestamp::date < '06-01-2018' 
        and (reservation_confirmed_at at time zone 'EDT')::timestamp::date < '05-28-2018'
        and city <> 'XXXX'
        and reservations.deleted_at is null
            group by rollup(city)
) as t2018
on t2018.City = t2019.City
order by city asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

A SELECT command is missing in your script. Please try adding the SELECT as below-

```
select
"City",
"2019 AAA",
"2019 BBB",
"2019 CCC",
"2018 AAA",
"2018 BBB",
"2018 CCC"

from ( SELECT -- This select is missing
coalesce(city, 'Total') as "City", 
....
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that! It says that issue is now with t2018.city

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: ERROR: column t2018.city does not exist Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "t2018.City". Position: 1866